# How to Install apache httpd from source for jboss clustering

Tags: apache, jboss, jboss7.x

I am currently setting up a JBoss EAP 7 cluster in domain mode and the goal is for an apache webserver to be installed as a load balancer. However, I am unable to install the httpd service from yum repositories as this is a VM that was provisioned by a client. I need to install httpd from its source which I have downloaded. My problem is that I am not sure about the configuration options to enable for this purpose. Any help would be appreciated. From the official [website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html), the instruction doesn't give details about what modules to be enabled and I'm not sure which of them are relevant for my own purpose.

```
Download    Download the latest release from http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi
Extract     $ gzip -d httpd-NN.tar.gz
$ tar xvf httpd-NN.tar
$ cd httpd-NN
Configure   $ ./configure --prefix=PREFIX
Compile     $ make
Install     $ make install
Customize   $ vi PREFIX/conf/httpd.conf
Test    $ PREFIX/bin/apachectl -k start
```

Answer (score 1):

Above provided [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html) will contain all module which provided with default Apache httpd. You can download the Apache httpd source folder and check module information in modules.In Apache source `module/proxy` folder contains module information regarding the proxy configuration. i.e mod_proxy module.

Comment: thanks @Pandurant, I have looked through that before

Comment: Yes please any more information would definitely be of help, however, I have been able to do the installation by following the link I posted in my answer

Comment: Even you can achieve load balancing without Mod_cluster in Apache httpd. Default Apache contains a mod_proxy(ReverseProxy) and mod_proxy_balancer module. You can achieve the same functionality with the inbuilt module

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do my installation by following the guide [here](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2224116/jboss-as7-clustering-using-mod-cluster-and-http-2-4--part-1-.html)